# How many moderators are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, moderators

I'd like to know how many moderators are there on Stack Overflow?

- Are they available 24 x 7?
- May I know the moderators names (if possible)?

Comment: Most of the mods names are their user names on the SO sites.

Comment: Although they don't have scheduled hours, the mods are very active and you can usually get a response from one of them fairly quickly if you flag something.

Comment: Anyone with a ♦ next to their name in the Users page is a moderator for that site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All of the moderators have a ♦ symbol next to their user names. The list of diamond moderators is available under the "Moderators" tab on the "Users" page of every site. For example, here is the link for the moderators on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

The `/users?tab=moderators` portion will be the same for all Stack Exchange sites.

There is also global moderator list available on Stack Exchange [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators). This lists each of the moderators per site for all of the sites in the Stack Exchange network.

It is worth noting that certain Stack Exchange employees (such as developers and [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338)) have diamonds and therefore the ability to moderate sites. However, because they are not *elected* moderators, they are not displayed in the list of moderators. (They will also have "Staff" badges on their usercards.)

Also, some would consider users who have achieved a certain reputation level to be "moderators". While they are not diamond moderators, and have no ornamentation on their usercards, reputation does brings certain moderator-style privileges, such as the ability to close questions (3k+) and view deleted posts (10k+). Current vernacular tends to call these users "curators", rather than "moderators", so that the term "moderators" can be reserved strictly for diamond moderators, who have full privileges (such as the ability to handle flags, see user information, issue suspensions, etc.).

Diamond moderators are strictly *volunteers*, so they are not guaranteed to be available 24/7. (Although, since this is a global site, it is somewhat likely that at least one moderator is around almost all the time.)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the moderators on each site's user's page on their own tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators

https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators

Also, all of the moderators at the above sites are moderators here at meta:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators